# I am merging to list with ascending order

Tags: python

If either i or j reach the end of their list range, how i copy the remainder of the other
list to the merge list
https://ibb.co/m9JzBYp
go to link if not get the question

```
 def list_merge (x, y):
    merge = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    total = len (x) + len(y)
    while != total :
       if x[i] < y[j]:
       merge.append(x[i])
       i += 1
       if i >= len (x):
      #how i copy the reminder
    else :
      merge.append(y[j])
      j += 1
      if j >= len (y):
     #how i copy the reminder
    return merge
```

Comment: please indent your code well

Comment: @azro visit the link of image

Comment: https://ibb.co/gR35Vs1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - OP wanted the code in some specific way.. Please see second snippet.

Don't try to complicate your code.. just go with how you would do it manually and write the code.

```
def list_merge (x, y):
    merged_list = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    # when one of them is empty, break out
    while i < len(x) and j < len(y):
      if x[i] <= y[j]:
        merged_list.append(x[i])
        i +=1
      else:
        merged_list.append(y[j])
        j +=1
    
    # if you are here, that means either one of the list is done
    # so check the bounds of both lists and append the one which is not traversed

    # x has some elements to add
    # check how extend works... makes your code clean
    if i != len(x):
      merged_list.extend(x[i:])
    else:
      merged_list.extend(y[j:])

    return merged_list

a = [1,3,5,7,10]
b = [2,4,6,8,100]
print(list_merge(a,b))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 100]
```

**What OP needed**

```
def list_merge (x, y):
  merge = []
  i = 0
  j = 0
  total = len (x) + len(y)
  while len(merge) != total :
    if x[i] < y[j]:
      merge.append(x[i])
      i += 1
      if i >= len (x):
        merge.extend(y[j:])
    else:
      merge.append(y[j])
      j += 1
      if j >= len (y):
        merge.extend(x[i:])

  return merge
```

Comment: here is image that i want to implement 
https://ibb.co/m9JzBYp

Comment: please check this out

Comment: check out this link please and help me

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed added new code that way questions asks for it... but tbh, you should have used my previous code to help yourself

Comment: am not learning python 
that was a question paper so i just have to fill the blanks for my younger brother's assignment 
i am an ios swift developer 
if you need any kind of help i am available

Answer (score 1):

a quite simple form:

```
def merge(*lists_in):
    list_in = []
    for l in lists_in:
        list_in += l

    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == list_in.__len__() -1:
            break
        if list_in[i] > list_in[i+1]:
            temp = list_in[i]
            list_in[i] = list_in[i+1]
            list_in[i+1] = temp
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1

    return list_in
```

Testing it:

```
list1 = [1,4] 
list2 = [1,5,6]
list3 = [3,7,9,10]

print(merge(list1, list2, list3))
```

Out:

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved rather nicely using deques, which allow you to efficiently look at *and* remove the first element.

```
from collections import deque

# A generator function that interleaves two sorted deques
# into a single sorted sequence.
def merge_deques(x, y):
    while x and y:
        yield (x if x[0] <= y[0] else y).popleft()
    
    # When we reach this point, one of x or y is empty,
    # so one of these doesn't yield any values.
    yield from x
    yield from y
    

# Makes a list by consuming the merged sequence of two deques.
def list_merge(x, y):
    return list(merge_deques(deque(x), deque(y))
```